# What should I do if my seat belt is faulty on a coach?

Tags: safety, buses, turkey, seating

Seat belt is mandatory (by Highways Traffic Law and Regulations) for all seats of intercity coaches in Turkey. I wonder what I should do if my seat belt is faulty and there is no option to change the seat (for example, all seats are occupied).

Are there spare seat belts on the coaches? If not, what should I do?

Comment: @JonathanReez If I really encountered this issue, that would be the first thing to do, but I just wonder what the common practice is (after asking the driver of course).

Comment: The chances of spare seat belts being carried on the bus is fairly low.  You have to decide to stay on or wait for the next bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the company gives you an alternative or not. Either way, it's then up to you to decide to move ahead or not. If no alternative is provided and you decide to go ahead and you end up in an accident, the company should be liable, but you might be dead.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience most people don't care about seat belts in Turkey. So if there is no free seat, you might just ask other passengers if they would like to switch seats with you.